# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_quantum'

Tags: python, tensorflow, quantum-computing, tensorflow-quantum

I'm using Python 3.8(64-bit)

Basically, I tried every possible solution on the internet like update the python version and tensorflow version etc.

But when I try to do this:

```
import tensorflow_quantum as tfq
```

terminal always say:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_quantum'
```

Does anyone have any idea on this issue? Cheers

Comment: Sorry if it is too stupid but did you install the package? `pip3 install -U tensorflow-quantum`

Comment: I have several suggestions, based on my slight research. It seems that either python 3.8 does not support TensorFlow quantum module, or installation instructions are not capable for later python (3.7+) versions. Check https://github.com/tensorflow/quantum/issues/213

Comment: when I try to do this "pip3 install -U tensorflow-quantum", system shows: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-quantum (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-quantum

Comment: I remember they updated to support python 3.8 64bit

Comment: As I see, it yet doesn't support tensorflow quantum, and it's a pity. You have better to dig deeper and find out exactly, but it seems that you have no option but downgrade your python to 3.6 or at least 3.7. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Please run the following:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install tensorflow==2.3.1
pip3 install -U tensorflow-quantum
```

Comment: Hi, for the first two, system shows:"Requirement already satisfied:"
But for the third one, showing: 
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-quantum (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-quantum

Answer (score 0):

I have faced quite a similar problem and I followed [this link](https://programmersought.com/article/75736365127/) for some help

in short I created a virtual environment with

```
python version == 3.6.2
conda create -n your_new_env_name python=3.6.2 anaconda
```

and then activated this environment as follows before you continue

```
conda activate your_new_env_name
```

then installed tensorflow

```
pip install tensorflow==2.1.0
pip install tensorflow-gpu=2.0.0
pip install tensorflow-quantum
```

you may face 2 errors which you might need to be solved

the first is this
When importing tensorflow, I get the following error:

> ```
> No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
> ```

all you have to do is this

```
pip install numpy --upgrade
```

or if needed

```
pip install numpy --upgrade --user
```

you may also get an error when import tensorflow-quantum that's related to **google.api_core** and what solved the problem for me was to do the following

```
pip install google.api_core==1.16.0
```

you may also need to the following

```
pip install cython
```

I hope it works!

Comment: Hi there - just a tip, Stackoverflow is compatible with markdown syntax. Enclosing code blocks with "\`" makes them more readable. `An example.`